# How to output \n from txt

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hello im new at Javascript and im making a bot with discord.js. I'm currently working on a bot that reponds to slash commands with random sentences that gets from txt file. I'm spliting responds with
this code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const file = "file.txt";
const text = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf-8");
const array = text.split("\n")
```

this my txt file:

```
1\n2
3\n4
5\n6
```

but when i use command bot sends:

```
1\n2
```

but i want to get:

```
1
2
```

also this my full code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require(`@discordjs/builders`);
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
const scriptName = path.basename(__filename);
const command = scriptName.slice(0, -3);
const file = `./texts/${command}.txt`;
const text = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf-8");
const array = text.split("\n")



function getRandomItem(arr) {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  const item = arr[randomIndex];
  return item;
}




module.exports = {
  
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
     .setName(`${command}`)
     .setDescription(`meeeoww??`),
  async execute(interation) {
    interation.reply({
      content: `${getRandomItem(array)}`,
      emphemral: true });
  },  
};
```

can anyone help me about that? (sorry if i did grammar errors im not native speaker)

Comment: Try changing `"\n"` to `"\\n"`

Comment: It still sends 1\n2

Comment: I thiink we might be missing some more context, what do you do with `array` after you create it? Maybe add a bit more of your code to the question.

Comment: i added full code of command file

Comment: Try replacing `"\n"` with `/\n|\\n/` -- notice there are no quotes around it, just `text.split(/\n|\\n/)`

Comment: Sorry i forgot remove quates its sending `1 to 6 ` now but im not wanting that i want keep it aspect one line in code but get aspect 2 line in discord

Comment: like this https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/982640061797498951/992100646369108008/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you replaced the `\n` string with the `\n` escape character. You can use:

```
let array = text.split("\n");
array = array.map(line => line.replace(/\\n/, "\n"));
```

or:

```
const array = text.split("\n");
// ...
interaction.reply({
    content: `${getRandomItem(array).replace(/\\n/, "\n")}`,
    ephemeral: true
})
```